# Having problems with group-wise maximum of a certain column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to find for each genre of movie, find the N actors who have played in most movies of the genre

Tables and their columns:

```
actor(actor_id,name)
role(actor_id,movie_id)
movie(movie_id,title)
movie_has_genre(movie_id,genre_id)
genre(genre_id,genre_name)
```

I started doing this:

```
select genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id,count(genre.genre_name) as max_value from genre
inner join movie_has_genre on movie_has_genre.genre_id=genre.genre_id
inner join movie on movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
inner join role on movie.movie_id=role.movie_id
inner join actor on actor.actor_id=role.actor_id
group by genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id 
order by max_value desc;
```

which gives me for every genre of movies,the actors and how many movies of this genre they have played and I want to find the actor that has played the most movies of every genre so i tried this:

```
 select genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id,count(genre.genre_name) 
from(select genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id,count(genre.genre_name) as max_value from genre
inner join movie_has_genre on movie_has_genre.genre_id=genre.genre_id
inner join movie on movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
inner join role on movie.movie_id=role.movie_id
inner join actor on actor.actor_id=role.actor_id
group by genre.genre_name,actor.actor_id 
order by max_value desc) as apotelesmata
group by genre.genre_name;
```

and I get as an error from mysql workbench that it doesnt recognise pretty much everything i have on my outer select function.My question is what should I do to
get the right results.
With the first code I gave I get this:

```
Thriller    22591   7
Drama   22591   6
Crime   65536   3
Horror  22591   3
Thriller    812916  3
Action  292028  3
Action  378578  3
Thriller    292028  3
Thriller    378578  3
```

But I want to get this:

```
Thriller    22591   7
Drama   22591   6
Crime   65536   3
Horror  22591   3
Action  292028  3
Action  378578  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, rather ugly:

```
SELECT t1.genre_name, t1.actor_id, t1.max_value
FROM
(
    SELECT g.genre_name, a.actor_id, COUNT(*) AS max_value
    FROM genre g
    INNER JOIN movie_has_genre mhg ON mhg.genre_id = g.genre_id
    INNER JOIN movie m ON mhg.movie_id = m.movie_id
    INNER JOIN role r ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id
    INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = r.actor_id
    GROUP BY g.genre_name, a.actor_id
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT genre_name, MAX(max_value) AS max_value
    FROM
    (
        SELECT g.genre_name, a.actor_id, COUNT(*) AS max_value
        FROM genre g
        INNER JOIN movie_has_genre mhg ON mhg.genre_id = g.genre_id
        INNER JOIN movie m ON mhg.movie_id = m.movie_id
        INNER JOIN role r ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id
        INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = r.actor_id
        GROUP BY g.genre_name, a.actor_id
    ) t
    GROUP BY genre_name
) t2
    ON t1.genre_name = t2.genre_name and t1.max_value = t2.max_value
ORDER BY
    t1.max_value DESC;
```

The verbosity of this answer has to do with that the base table for your question is actually a query already involving 4 joins.  This table needs to be repeated in MySQL because we don't have analytic functions.  Also, we don't have common table expressions, which could also make the query much more concise.

Comment: at start it said that it was ambiguous cause of the first select function.fixed it.Then guess what...same error :P

Comment: no errors and the result seem what i want thank you very much

Comment: lets say i want to limit to lets say 5 for each genre where should i place the LIMIT function?

Comment: @stef You can't easily do this in MySQL.  You'd need to use session variables, and the resulting query would probably be even longer than what I posted.  If you have these long term needs, then either upgrade to MySQL 8, or switch to another DB.